# Is there a De Facto Utility for Type Conversion in Java?

Tags: java

There are lots of cases where Java applications interface with other systems and need to translate between different types of objects. Typical examples include web frameworks for HTTP request parameter mapping and JDBC frameworks for persisting to databases.

However, it seems like every framework has its own set of type converters for doing this, and I'm surprised about that given the prevalence of this type conversion requirement. Particularly since we're now on Java 8, is there yet a standard, established library for type conversion?

Comment: Could you expand on what you would expect that library to do? Some examples, like SAP, Oracle, SOAP, Jax-WS and how they are similar to each other would help. While I would like such a library as well, I doubt there is one generic as this is just too diverse.

Comment: I'm thinking of the situation where, for example, you read a value from an XML element or an HTTP request parameter (as a String, in this example) and you need to convert that value into a date or a monetary amount.  While many XML or HTTP frameworks support this String-to-Object conversion, they all have their own internal ways of doing it under the hood.  I'm wondering whether this type conversion feature exists as a utility in its own right.